# Scraper only prints last page data instead of all pages - BS4

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am scraping Trustpilot reviews, but data keeps getting overwritten with each iteration. How can I make it append all data from all pages instead of just the last one?

```
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook 


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_total_items(url):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, format(0),headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}).text, 'lxml')
    stars = []
    star1 = soup.find_all(attrs={"star-rating star-rating--medium"})
    stars.append(star1)
    df = pd.DataFrame(stars, ["Rating"])
    return df

ddf = []
for i in range(29): 
    urls = "https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.pandora.net?page={}"  
    get_total_items(urls).append(ddf)

print(ddf)
```

Comment: you are providing always the same url to get_total_items? you are maybe missing to concatenate the `i` inside `page={}`?

Answer (score 3):

Change the for loop like below:

```
for i in range(29): 
    urls = "https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.pandora.net?page={}"  
    ddf.append(get_total_items(urls.format(i)))
```